# get id/name values inside iframe context

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

If you have an iframe like this

```
<iframe id="abc" name="xyz" src="..."></iframe>
```

Is there a way inside that iframe to determine what the value if **id** and **name** is?

The only way I can think of is to sendMessage that information from the **window.top** context to that iframe. But maybe there is a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: Only if the iframe content was loaded from the same origin as the parent page, you could directly access the iframe _element_ in the parent page, from within the iframe. (Although you might still need to find a way to identify the correct one then, if there could be more iframes on the page.) If not, then you will need some cross-origin communication here - usually done via `postMessage` these days.

Comment: If you could append id and name to the iframe'd document's URL to begin with, then the document inside the iframe could read them from there. (Query string parameters, or fragment.)